# Conservation of probability in Jaynes-Cummings model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

I was reading about Jaynes-Cummings model. I've studied Bachelor level QM.
In the interaction picture the solution with *rotating wave approximation* and *initial conditions* $C_g(0)=0$ and $C_e(0)=1$ is of the form

$$|\Psi(t) \rangle = \sum_{n} \{ -iC_{n-1} \sin(\lambda \sqrt{n} t)|g\rangle + C_n \cos(\lambda \sqrt{n+1} t)|e\rangle \} |n \rangle$$
where $\sum_{n}C_n |n\rangle$ is the state of the field at $t=0$.

From this, to me it seems like the probability is not conserved --- I mean, should it not be so that 
$$ |iC_{n-1} \sin(\lambda \sqrt{n}t)|^2 + |C_n \cos(\lambda \sqrt{n+1} t)|^2 = 1?$$
Clearly it isn't. Why? What does it mean?

Comment: I think you have forgotten a sum over $n$. If you have a reference you are following, that would also help.

Comment: True, I didn't sum over n. It still seems like this wouldn't hold generally, since the arguments in sin and cos are different. 
[I also could have chosen the field to be initially at state $|n\rangle$, right?]
And Im following Knight's Introductory Quantum Optics, if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to just show you how to do this right, and then I'll try to comment on what you did wrong.

The JC model for a two level system coupled to a harmonic oscillator has the following Hamiltonian in the case that the two systems are on resonance:

$$ H = g ( \sigma_- a^{\dagger} + \sigma_+ a ) $$

where $\sigma_-$ and $\sigma_+$ are the raising and lowering operators for the two level system, and $a^{\dagger}$ and $a$ are the raising and lowering operators for the harmonic oscillator. This is written in the rotation frame in which the independent Hamiltonians for the two level system and the oscillator go to zero.

This Hamiltonian does not change the total number of excitations in the system, ie. it is block diagonal, connecting only states $\left| g,\, n \right. \rangle$ and $\left| e, \, n-1 \right. \rangle$. Therefore, we can work out what happens between two connected states, and we know that the other pairs work in the same way.

In one of the blocks the matrix for the Hamiltonian is

$$H = g \sqrt{n} \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right] = g\sqrt{n}\sigma_x.$$

If you compute the time evolution of this thing you get an evolution operator of

$$U(t) = \exp\left[ -i\frac{g t \sqrt{n}}{\hbar} \sigma_x \right].$$

You can actually just compute this using basic infinite sums, and you get

$$U(t) = \cos\left(gt\sqrt{n}/\hbar \right) \textbf{1} -i \sin\left(gt\sqrt{n}/\hbar \right)\sigma_x.$$

Ok, now let's take your initial state $\left| \Psi(0) \right.\rangle=\left|e,\,n-1 \right.\rangle$. Applying $U(t)$ to that gives

$$\left| \Psi(t) \right.\rangle = U(t)\left|\Psi(0)\right.\rangle = \cos\left(gt\sqrt{n}/\hbar\right)\left|e,\,n-1\right.\rangle - i\sin\left(gt\sqrt{n}/\hbar\right)\left|g,\,n\right.\rangle.$$

This state is obviously correctly normalized. You should compare this to your first equation with $\lambda = g/\hbar$.

I'll write more if you can't figure it out from here.